# Indian national travelling from Namibia to US through Barbados, transit visa required?

Tags: visas

I am a student studying in US on a valid F-1 student visa, I will be going to Namibia and on my way back, I will transit through Barbados (actually also spend a night at a hotel in Barbados) do I need a visa for Barbados?

Answer (score 2):

Indian citizens transiting Barbados need a visa to leave the airport, or for transit times exceeding 12 hours.

From [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&HEALTH=1&VISA=1&NA=IN&EM=US&DE=NA&TR=BB&PASSTYPES=PASS&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C):

> Visa required, except for Holders of confirmed onward tickets for a max. transit time of 12 hours.